# Issue related to Async nodejs - giving inaccurate response

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, express

Most probably there is some mistake that I have done and it is so small that I have failed to identify it.

**Code Snippet** -

```
async.parallel
([
function(callback)
{
    pictureset.findOne({ 'jebno': newz }, function (err, docsss)
    { 
        if (err) return callback(err);
        pictures = docsss;
        console.log(docsss);
        callback();
    });

},

function(callback)

{
    merchantmodel.findOne({ 'jebno': newz1 }, function (err, docss)
    { 
        if (err) return callback(err);
        merchantobject = docss;
        console.log(docss);
        callback();
    });

},

function(err)
{

    console.log(pictures);
    console.log(merchantobject);
    console.log("We are here");
    res.json({ picturemodel: pictures, merchantobject: merchantobject, status: 100, message: 'Successfully Done1'});            

    if (err) return next(err);
}
]);
```

Now I am expecting a response like this.

```
Value from console.log(docsss);
Value from console.log(docss);
Value from console.log(pictures);
Value from console.log(merchantobject); 
we are here
```

But the response I am getting on my console is

1. Undefined
2. Undefined
3. We are here
4. Some array related message which I have seen before but it didn't really change the outcome in those cases. I did some research on it and failed to understand its exact meaning.
5. Values from console.log(docsss) & console.log(docss)

**Here is the actual snippet of console**

```
undefined
undefined
We are here
function () {
            var length = Math.max(arguments.length - startIndex, 0);
            var rest = Array(length);
            for (var index = 0; index < length; index++) {
                rest[index] = arguments[index + startIndex];
            }
            switch (startIndex) {
                case 0: return func.call(this, rest);
                case 1: return func.call(this, arguments[0], rest);
            }
            // Currently unused but handle cases outside of the switch statement:
            // var args = Array(startIndex + 1);
            // for (index = 0; index < startIndex; index++) {
            //     args[index] = arguments[index];
            // }
            // args[startIndex] = rest;
            // return func.apply(this, args);
        }
{ _id: 5612c8950e1489f419ae1f0f,
  jebno: '1231checka',
  __v: 0,
  photos:
   [ '1445524441140_12023123_10156249375555727_859908445_n.jpg',
     '1445524452856_12063857_919875394745615_3655186829888867333_n.jpg',
     '1445524452873_491676259.jpg',
     '1445524482917_12023123_10156249375555727_859908445_n.jpg',
     '1445524894340_7a668c73cddcd2050821f83be901832a_1426070017.jpg',
     '1445524894365_577161_424797084279112_1944605947_n.jpg',
     '1445525002813_12063857_919875394745615_3655186829888867333_n.jpg' ] }
{ _id: 56645b9b29422ebad43b59be,
  name: 'Ramesh Sharma',
  email: 'ramesh@gmail.com',
  password: 'ramesh',
  jebno: '1455',
  mobileno: '123456754',
  address: 'Ramesh Chowk',
  coverphoto: '1449689932496_12243392_10153773144324749_4504520513350378845_n.jpg',
  ratings: 4,
  totalratings: 12 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`async.parallel` does take an array of tasks *and* a callback, not the callback as the last array element.

Your code should look like this:

```
async.parallel([
    function(callback) {
        pictureset.findOne({ 'jebno': newz }, callback);
    },
    function(callback) {
        merchantmodel.findOne({ 'jebno': newz1 }, callback);
    }
], function(err, results) {
    if (err) return next(err);

    var pictures = results[0],
        merchantobject = results[1];
    console.log(pictures);
    console.log(merchantobject);
    console.log("We are here");
    res.json({
        picturemodel: pictures,
        merchantobject: merchantobject,
        status: 100,
        message: 'Successfully Done1'
    });            
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time Bergi. How is this solution different from what the other person has posted. I am curious and I'll do more research on points you will give.

Comment: @RanganathanSwamy: It doesn't log the objects twice, but it is much more efficient and concise (and doesn't require those outer-scope variables - you did declare them somewhere, right?). I've also moved the error handling code to not send a response in case of an error, which is probably cleaner.

Comment: Amazing _/\_. Thanks a ton. It's really sad that I cannot accept two answers. @idbehold's answer is adequate as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the final callback function as a second argument after the array of callback functions you want to run in parallel:

```
async.parallel([
    function(callback){
        pictureset.findOne({ 'jebno': newz }, function (err, docsss){ 
            if (err) return callback(err);
            pictures = docsss;
            console.log(docsss);
            callback();
        });
    },
    function(callback){
        merchantmodel.findOne({ 'jebno': newz1 }, function (err, docss){ 
            if (err) return callback(err);
            merchantobject = docss;
            console.log(docss);
            callback();
        });
    }
],
// optional callback
function(err, results){
    console.log(pictures);
    console.log(merchantobject);
    console.log("We are here");
    res.json({ picturemodel: pictures, merchantobject: merchantobject, status: 100, message: 'Successfully Done'});            

    if (err) return next(err);
});
```

Comment: Thank you idbehold for your time. I have tried your solution and it works properly. Same thing I'd like to add here, how is this solution different from what the other person has posted? I'm curious and I will read more on points you'll lay down. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ranganathan, both the answers essentially illustrate the same thing the explanations is as follows:

You pass an array of functions to async.parallel. It runs them all at the same time. You don't know in what order they will start, or when they will end.

The last function, which as the answers pointed out, needed to be outside the array, is the final callback. It gets called in two situations:

One, all the functions passed in the array above it have completed successfully. If you have provided some data in the callback within each function, that data will show up in the results array. The error object (err), would be null.

Two, if there are any errors produced, then the error object (err) passed to the final function will contain an actual error. You need to deal with that error in some way in your code.

Comment: @Bergi's followup comment helped me to understand that and I did some more study on the subject as well. Thanks for your detailed explanation.